# TableLayoutPanel Column Ordering and Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, tablelayoutpanel

Our app is targeting .net4.0, code is mix of projects in vb.net and c#. This particular project is vb.net. My dev machine is windows 7x64 pro with vs 2010 sp1 and a VS2010 + Windows 8x64 VMWare machine.

In windows 7 our tablelayoutpanel shows correctly in design time and the resultant executable winforms application. However running our application in Wondows 8 we saw that the order of columns in TableLayoutPanels are mixed up.

I have attached a screenshot, now at first we just thought its something to do with the way windows 8 works and hopeed that a recompile in windows 8 would fix it. Nope! Opening the same source file in windows 8 shows as per the attached screenshot, mixed up columns. So we fixed the ordering, compiled and in windows 8 it shows up fine, but back in windows 7 we get the mixed up column orders all over again.

So fix it in either windows 7 or 8 and the other shows incorrectly?

Can anyone offer any suggestions? its not like we can email Microsoft for an answer and expect a fix any time soon.

[image: screenshot]

Edit: We are really stuck with this, does have any ideas/suggestion?

Edit2: MSDN Community Support told me to raise it with connect.microsoft.com, which i have done but i dont expect it to ever be solved. So i will have to replace this user control with something else and hope i dont find other user controls with similar issues or Windows 8 support will just get shelved permanently.
Going to close this on the basis that its accepted as a bug and wont be fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue.
I have a response from connect.microsoft, its fixed in 4.5 8th Jan 2013 patch release.

---

Posted by Microsoft on 17/01/2013 at 17:52 
Thank you for your feedback. We are able to reproduce this issue and confirmed that it had been fixed in the recently release update to .Net Framework 4.5 that is available on Windows Updates starting on the 8th of January.

Many customers have found it useful to discuss issues like this in the forums (http://www.microsoft.com/communities/forums/default.mspx) where Microsoft and other members of the community can suggest workarounds.  Please keep the feedback coming.

Thanks,
The Windows Forms Team

Answer (score 1):

–My lame suggestion is to try 'rolling your own' - maybe the two versions of the ide are scrambling the order.

all the table layout that you are showing above can be done with code, and that might avoid the trouble you are seeing with windows 8 and windows 7
I found this at
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/4e6bc84b-b465-4bee-9316-c0ee68d9fa20

Dim tlp As New TableLayoutPanel
        tlp.ColumnCount = 3
        tlp.RowCount = 5
        tlp.AutoSize = True

```
    Dim labels(4) As Label  
    For i As Byte = 0 To 4  
        labels(i) = New Label  
        labels(i).Text = "Label number " & i  
        tlp.Controls.Add(labels(i), 0, i)  
    Next i  

    Dim comboboxes(4) As ComboBox  
    For i As Byte = 0 To 4  
        comboboxes(i) = New ComboBox  
        comboboxes(i).Items.AddRange _  
        (New String() {"first item", "second item", "item number 3"})  
        tlp.Controls.Add(comboboxes(i), 1, i)  
    Next i  

    Dim firstRowButton As New Button  
    firstRowButton.Text = "New button!" 

    tlp.Controls.Add(firstRowButton, 2, 0)  

    Dim thirdRowTextBox As New TextBox  
    tlp.Controls.Add(thirdRowTextBox, 2, 2)  

    Me.Controls.Add(tlp)
```

Good luck

Comment: Yeah i suspect i will have to create and enforce the ordering manually. thanks for the time to reply.